# Monitor current line number while running DWScript?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

I'm using the latest DWScript which has a TdwsDebugger component with it. However I'm not necessarily looking to provide debugging tools to the user - just visually show the current line number.

In the `TdwsDebugger` component, in its `OnDebug` event, `expr.ScriptPos` seems to provide me with this information. But I'm trying to figure out how to make use of this without actually "debugging".

How can I show current DWScript line number without implementing debugging?

Comment: A SynEdit memo could display the script and highlight the executing line.

Comment: @MartynA Indeed, I'm using `TSynEdit`, but I need access to the current line # from DWS.

Comment: I took a quick look at the DWScript source at it's not glaringly obvious how to do this, but equally, it's not clear how you could do what you want without actually debugging: after all, if DWS has a free-running execution engine, it wouldn't (and shouldn't, itself) have any concept of a current line.  So I'm guessing that this info is only available when it's being  driven by a debugger, whose business it is to know how to keep track of the source code statement which corresponds to the currently-executing code.  Iyswim ...

Comment: Generally, it's the act of debugging that allows a program to inspect execution state of another program. So I think you do need to be debugging to know that.

Answer (score 1):

When no debugger is active, there is no code actively maintaining any current "line" or other particular execution information, so that information is not available.

Basically, when not debugging, the script execution engine tries to avoid any debugging-related overhead, which includes maintaining current line number or sending debug events notifications.